# Notification action buttons not working for Android 13

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-13

I have created a Notification with a pause and close button as below and it's working fine for Android level 12 and below. But for Android 13 the actions are not being triggered. Below are my service class and manifest files.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />

   <receiver
            android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.wecoders.singleradiopro.ui.radio.RadioService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            />
```

Here is my service class

```
public class RadioService extends Service implements Player.EventListener, AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener, MetadataOutput {

    public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.mcakir.radio.player.ACTION_PLAY";
    public static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "com.mcakir.radio.player.ACTION_PAUSE";
    public static final String ACTION_STOP = "com.mcakir.radio.player.ACTION_STOP";

    private final IBinder iBinder = new LocalBinder();
    MetadataListener callbacks;

    private SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
    private MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;
    private MediaControllerCompat.TransportControls transportControls;

    private boolean onGoingCall = false;
    private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;

    private WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock;

    private AudioManager audioManager;

    private MediaNotificationManager notificationManager;

    private String status;


    private Radio radio;
    private String streamUrl;
    public String radioName;


    private static final String TAG = "RadioService";


    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public RadioService getService() {
            return RadioService.this;
        }
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver becomingNoisyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            pause();
        }
    };

    private PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                    || state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {

                if (!isPlaying()) return;

                onGoingCall = true;
                stop();

            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {

                if (!onGoingCall) return;

                onGoingCall = false;
                resume();
            }
        }
    };

    /* private final TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener callStateListener = state -> {
         if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                 || state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {

             if (!isPlaying()) return;

             onGoingCall = true;
             stop();

         } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {

             if (!onGoingCall) return;

             onGoingCall = false;
             resume();
         }
     };
 */
    private MediaSessionCompat.Callback mediasSessionCallback = new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {


        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            Log.d(TAG, "MediaSessionCompat: on Pause");
            pause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            Log.d(TAG, "MediaSessionCompat: onStop");
            stop();

            notificationManager.cancelNotify();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            super.onPlay();

            resume();
        }
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBind: Service ");
        return iBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");


        onGoingCall = false;

        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        notificationManager = new MediaNotificationManager(this);

        wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
                .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mcScPAmpLock");

        Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this,
                    0, mediaButtonIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
        } else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this,
                    0, mediaButtonIntent,
                    0
            );
        }

        mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, getClass().getSimpleName(), null, pendingIntent);
        transportControls = mediaSession.getController().getTransportControls();
        mediaSession.setActive(true);
        mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
        mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "ON AIR")
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, radioName)
                .build());
        mediaSession.setCallback(mediasSessionCallback);


        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        // telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //telephonyManager.registerTelephonyCallback(getMainExecutor(), callStateListener);
            }
        } else {
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }


        exoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        exoPlayer.addListener(this);

        registerReceiver(becomingNoisyReceiver, new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY));

        status = PlaybackStatus.IDLE;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(action))
            return START_NOT_STICKY;

        int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        if (result != AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {

            stop();

            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PLAY)) {

            transportControls.play();

        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PAUSE)) {

            transportControls.pause();

        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_STOP)) {

            transportControls.stop();

        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        if (status.equals(PlaybackStatus.IDLE))
            stopSelf();

        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(final Intent intent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: RadioService");
        pause();

        exoPlayer.release();
        exoPlayer.removeListener(this);

        if (telephonyManager != null)
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);

        notificationManager.cancelNotify();

        mediaSession.release();

        unregisterReceiver(becomingNoisyReceiver);

        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {

        switch (focusChange) {
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:

                exoPlayer.setVolume(0.8f);

                resume();

                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:

                stop();

                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:

                if (isPlaying()) pause();

                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:

                if (isPlaying())
                    exoPlayer.setVolume(0.1f);

                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

        switch (playbackState) {
            case Player.STATE_BUFFERING:
                status = PlaybackStatus.LOADING;
                break;
            case Player.STATE_ENDED:
                status = PlaybackStatus.STOPPED;
                break;
            case Player.STATE_READY:
                status = playWhenReady ? PlaybackStatus.PLAYING : PlaybackStatus.PAUSED;
                break;
            case Player.STATE_IDLE:
            default:
                status = PlaybackStatus.IDLE;
                break;
        }

        if (!status.equals(PlaybackStatus.IDLE))
            notificationManager.startNotify(status);

        EventBus.getDefault().post(status);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, int reason) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

        EventBus.getDefault().post(PlaybackStatus.ERROR);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekProcessed() {

    }

    public void play(Radio radio) {
        this.radio = radio;
        this.streamUrl = radio.getStreamingLink();
        Log.e(TAG, "play: url ----> " + streamUrl);

        if (wifiLock != null && !wifiLock.isHeld()) {

            wifiLock.acquire();

        }
        exoPlayer.addMetadataOutput(this);
        exoPlayer.prepare(buildMediaSource(streamUrl));
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    private MediaSource buildMediaSource(String url) {
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "exoplayer-codelab");

        if (streamUrl.contains(".m3u8")) {
            return new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url));
        } else {
            return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url));
        }

    }

    public void setCallbacks(MetadataListener callbacks) {
        this.callbacks = callbacks;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMetadata(Metadata metadata) {
        Log.e("Metadata is --->>>", metadata.toString());

        for (int i = 0; i < metadata.length(); i++) {
            Metadata.Entry entry = metadata.get(i);
            // Log.e("onMetadata: IcyInfo", entry.toString());
            if (entry instanceof IcyInfo) {
                callbacks.onMetadataUpdated(((IcyInfo) entry).title, ((IcyInfo) entry).url);
                try {
                    callbacks.onMetadataUpdated(getArtistAndContent(metadata.toString()), getAlbumArt(metadata.toString()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    callbacks.onMetadataUpdated(getArtistAndContent(metadata.toString()), getAlbumArt(metadata.toString()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private String getArtistAndContent(String metaString) throws Exception {

        String firstString = "";
        String secondString = "";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(TIT2.*value)=(.*)(TPE1)");
        Matcher m;

        m = p.matcher(metaString);
        if (m.find()) {
            firstString = m.group(2).trim();
            if (firstString.endsWith(",")) {
                firstString = firstString.substring(0, firstString.length() - 1);
            }
            //Log.e("First value", " -> " + firstString);
        }

        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(TPE1.*value)=(.*)(WXXX)");
        Matcher m1;

        m1 = p1.matcher(metaString);
        if (m1.find()) {
            secondString = m1.group(2).trim();
            if (secondString.endsWith(",")) {
                secondString = secondString.substring(0, secondString.length() - 1);
            }
            // Log.e("Second value", " -> " + secondString);
        }

        String fullString = "null";

        try {
            fullString = firstString + " - " + secondString;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fullString;
    }

    private String getAlbumArt(String metaString) throws Exception {

        if (!metaString.contains("amgArtworkURL"))
            return "";

        String albumArt = "";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*amgArtworkURL=\")(.*)(\"\\slength)");
        Matcher m;

        m = p.matcher(metaString);
        if (m.find()) {
            albumArt = m.group(2).trim();
            Log.e("Album Art", " -> " + albumArt);
        }

        String url = "";

        try {
            url = albumArt;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return url;
    }


    public void resume() {

        if (radio != null)
            play(radio);
    }


    public void pause() {

        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);

        audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
        wifiLockRelease();
    }

    public void stop() {

        exoPlayer.stop();

        audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
        wifiLockRelease();
    }

    public void playOrPause(Radio radio) {
        if (!isPlaying()) {
            play(radio);
        } else {
            pause();
        }
    }


    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public MediaSessionCompat getMediaSession() {

        return mediaSession;
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {

        return this.status.equals(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
    }

    private void wifiLockRelease() {

        if (wifiLock != null && wifiLock.isHeld()) {

            wifiLock.release();
        }
    }


    public Radio getRadio() {
        return radio;
    }

    public void stopPlayer() {
        if (exoPlayer != null) {
            exoPlayer.stop();
            notificationManager.cancelNotify();
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is occurring for android 13 as for lower versions it's working fine. I have also added runtime permission for Notifications.

My NotificationManager class is as below:

```
public class MediaNotificationManager {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 555;
    private final String PRIMARY_CHANNEL = "PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID";
    private final String PRIMARY_CHANNEL_NAME = "PRIMARY";

    private RadioService service;


    String mRadioName;

    private Resources resources;

    private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationManager";

    public MediaNotificationManager(RadioService service) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MediaNotificationManager: service wala");

        this.service = service;
        this.resources = service.getResources();

        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(service);
    }


    public void startNotify(String playbackStatus) {

        final Bitmap[] largeIcon = new Bitmap[1];

        try {
            Glide.with(service.getApplicationContext())
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(service.getRadio().getImage())
                    .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>(100,100) {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            largeIcon[0] = resource;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                            largeIcon[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_radio_icon);
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            largeIcon[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_radio_icon);
        }


        int icon = R.drawable.exo_icon_pause;
        Intent playbackAction = new Intent(service, RadioService.class);
        playbackAction.setAction(RadioService.ACTION_PAUSE);

        PendingIntent action;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
            Log.e("inside", "pauise");
            action = PendingIntent.getService(service, 1, playbackAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }else{
            action = PendingIntent.getService(service, 1, playbackAction, 0);
        }

        if (playbackStatus.equals(PlaybackStatus.PAUSED)) {

            icon = R.drawable.exo_icon_play;
            playbackAction.setAction(RadioService.ACTION_PLAY);

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
                action = PendingIntent.getService(service, 2, playbackAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            }else{
                action = PendingIntent.getService(service, 2, playbackAction, 0);
            }


        }

        Intent stopIntent = new Intent(service, RadioService.class);
        stopIntent.setAction(RadioService.ACTION_STOP);

        PendingIntent stopAction;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
            stopAction = PendingIntent.getService(service, 3, stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }else{
            stopAction = PendingIntent.getService(service, 3, stopIntent, 0);
        }



        Intent intent = new Intent(service, MainActivity.class);

        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(service, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }else{
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(service, 0, intent, 0);
        }


        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) service.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL, PRIMARY_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(service, PRIMARY_CHANNEL)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setContentTitle(service.getRadio().getName())
                .setContentText("ON AIR")
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon[0])
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_radio_icon)
                .addAction(icon, "pause", action)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_close, "stop", stopAction)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(service.getMediaSession().getSessionToken())
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1)
                        .setShowCancelButton(true)
                        .setCancelButtonIntent(stopAction));

        service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }

    public void cancelNotify() {
        service.stopForeground(true);
    }

}
```